# What has changed in Ubuntu 20.04 with regards to lockdown?

Tags: kernel, 20.04, secure-boot

The [release notes for 20.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes#Linux_Kernel) state that the new 5.4 kernel has:

> Enablement of lockdown in integrity mode.

What does that mean? What has changed?

In 18.04 lockdown was already enabled for systems using Secure Boot.
Is this now automatically enabled for all installs? Or did the strictness somehow change?